# Understanding delegation pattern in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, delegation

I learn Delegation pattern from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern
 It confused me as follow:

1. Delegation Pattern == Method Overloading / Overriding
2. Delegation Pattern == Polymorphism

Is any of above true?

Comment: Taken from the article:  "Delegation is simply passing a duty off to someone/something else."  Though it can be used to implement overloading or polymorphism, this need not happen.  It is really a separate technique.

Comment: Have a look at this article - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/awt/designspec/events.html

Comment: To my understanding the article does not make any of the two statements you've listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. 
In a simple java example Object A has a method that turns around and calls a method on Object B. So you can say that A delegated to B.

In a complex example Object B implements Interface A but you can ask an interface A to perform a method and it will tell B to perform that method.

None of this really have much to do with polymorphism or overriding.

Answer (score 1):

None of them is true. Assume, A delegates something to B, then delegation is just invoking a method of another object B (which object A has declared internally) instead of performing this task by object A on its own.

Yes, method names are usually the same for both A and B (just due to common sense, most likely), but it's neither overloading nor polymorphism.

(In addition, delegation may be more complex. For example, object A choose a delegate (B, C or D,...) before delegation. And so on.)